# Как вставить информацию из базы данных в выпадающий список в tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite3, выпадающий-список

Я новичок, не могу разобраться в коде. Суть следующая, я хочу сделать выпадающее меню в окне tkinter, при этом данные для пункта меню я беру из базы данных main.db из таблицы orgs.
Таблица orgs содержит два столбца "Название организации" и "ИНН организации" и две записи:
ООО 123, 1234567890
ООО 321, 0987654321

```
con = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM orgs") 
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row[0])
```

Вывод в терминале даёт правильный, и тут я уже не знаю что сделать.
Вывод следующий(он то мне и нужен в выпадающем меню, но пока получается только вывести в терминале):

```
ООО 123
ООО 321
```

Далее я хочу вставить эти данные в выпадающее меню, но не получается.

```
variable = StringVar(root)

variable.set(row[0]) # устанавливаю значение по умолчанию, выдаёт почему-то вторую строку "ООО 321" без ИНН, а надо первую строку "ООО 123" без ИНН.

ispi = OptionMenu(framemain, variable, *row)
```

На этом этапе, при вызове выпадающего меню он мне выдаёт меню из двух строк "ООО 321" и "0987654321".
Вопрос:
Как взять информацию из первого столбца таблицы базы данных и поместить её в выпадающий список?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать ttk.Combobox: Он лучше как выпадающий список. И мороки с ним нет

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

### Запросы sql и тд

root = tk.Tk()
combo = ttk.Combobox(root)
combo.pack()

def add_value(v):
    combo['values'] = tuple(list(combo['values']) + ['v'])

add_value(row[0])

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо! Переосмыслил код через Combobox, попутно решились другие проблемы.